# Is it possible to connect MySQL zip archive with datagrip?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, datagrip

Is there any way to connect MySQL zip archive via path variable with datagrip?

Comment: What is inside this acrhive?

Comment: MySQL zip archive

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible because you need the running server